# \n is not being removed while converting HTML text with Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I want to convert Html to plain text.

**Requirements::**

1. line breaks should be preserved
2. Conversion of html string and html file should be same.

**FileContent::**

```html
<html>

<body>

  <h1>header tag</h1>

  <p>paragraph tag</p>

  <div>div1</div>

  <div>div2</div>

  <div>div3</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Following is code::**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("html.html"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            contentBuilder.append(str);
            contentBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    String content = contentBuilder.toString();
    
    String html="<html><body><h1>header tag</h1><p>paragraph tag</p><div>div1</div><div>div2</div><div>div3</div></body></html>";
    String output = HTMLtoPlainText(html);
    System.out.println("with  string::\n"+output);
    output = HTMLtoPlainText(content);
    System.out.println("with  html file::\n"+output);
}
private static String HTMLtoPlainText(String html) {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    document.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
    document.select("div").before("\n");
 
    String output=Jsoup.clean(document.html(), "", Whitelist.none(), new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
output=Parser.unescapeEntities(output, false);
    return output;
}
```

**Output is:**

*with  string:*

header tagparagraph tag

div1

div2

div3

**with  html file:**

header tag

paragraph tag

div1

div2

div3

After executing same method for these two different input we got different output like ,

**In case of FileContent:**

I got new lines before header tag and new line between header tag and paragraph tag.[Reason i analyzed is we got \n characters between tags and there are not being replaced automatically by clean method]

So what should I use so that I can get same result for these two different inputs?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode please insert your html snippets into your example code, making it a mcve (http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Comment: how you are reading the file content? show us that part also.

Comment: Actually while reading the file I have added '\n' explicitly. Actually that type of data we got from some API. For reproducing the same behaviour I have used file and explicitly added '\n'. I have edited the code and added file reading code

Comment: from API you are getting `\n` included string ? what is the api response , what exactly you are getting from that api?

Comment: API response I can not show. But the output of file reading is exactly same which we got as a API response. Temporarily I have replaced '\n' with space like I added html=html.replaceAll(html) before line Document document = Jsoup.parse(html); But I want to do this without replaceAll if possible.